# Command to open directly "download new plasma widgets"

Tags: command-line, software-installation, kde, plasma, plasma-widgets

Widgets are an essential part of Plasma/KDE, and I have always found rather odd and cumbersome the way of accessing the interface to install them, by

- right-clicking the panel or the desktop,
- selecting "Add widgets", *then*:
- "Get new widgets", *then*:
- "Download new... ...

Can we get a command (and a launcher for that) that would simply open this window?

[image]